# How to prove that the transpose of an elementary matrix is an elementary matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, transpose

I'm having a hard time to prove this statement. I tried everything like using the inverse etc. but couldn't find anything.

I've tried to prove it by using **E=€(I)**, where **E** is the elementary matrix and **I** is the identity matrix and **€** is the elementary row operation. Took transpose both sides etc. Still nothing.

Comment: I dont understand your difficulty, the transpose of "adding c time row k to row l" is "adding c times row l to row k"

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, wouldn't this be adding c* column k to column l?

Answer (score 2):

Considering elementary matrices for row transformation, we can have 3 cases:

1. Transpose of elementary matrix of $R_i\Leftarrow R_i+ \alpha R_j $ is the elementary matrix of $R_j \Leftarrow R_j + \alpha R_i $
2. Transpose of elementary matrix of $ R_i \leftrightarrow R_j $ is the matrix itself due to symmetry.
3. Transpose of elementary matrix of $R_i \Leftarrow \alpha R_i $ is the matrix itself due to symmetry.

Therefore, transpose of every elementary matrix is an elementary matrix.